# Is it really possible to use a different convention to lay out source directory without breaking intra-package references?

Tags: python, pip, distutils

Suppose you are working on a python package. Here is the structure of the package (expressed in terms of a hierarchical file system):

```
/PackageName
    /src
        __init__.py
        /subpackage1
            __init__.py
            module1a.py
            module1b.py
        /subpackage2
            __init__.py
            module2a.py
            module2b.py
    /tests
    INSTALL
    LICENSE
    README
    setup.py
```

Distutils is used to build, distribute and install the package. In the setup script it is possible to tell Distutils about my convention to lay out my source directory (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages)). In short I would put:

```
package_dir = {'packagename', 'src'}
```

However there is an issue when for example `module1a` needs to import `module2a` with an absolute import (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)). In short I would put in `module1a`:

```
import src.module2a
```

Once the package distributed and installed with `pip` a simple:

```
import packagename
```

raises:

```
ImportError: No module names src.module2a
```

A simple solution will be to rename `src` directory to `packagename` but (as my question clearly states) is there a solution to use a different convention to lay out source directory (perhaps a `distutils` or `pip` option I missed).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `src` directory is not meant to be a package name; it shouldn't have an `__init__.py` file even. It is meant to be part of your `sys.modules` search path instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That may be true in general, but in this case it looks like a misuse of `src`, since the OP apparently does want the subpackages to be *sub*packages of `PackageName`.  Putting `src` directly on `sys.path` would mean you import the subpackages directly at the top level, without going through `PackageName`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: see my answer below, the OP is missing the actual package directory.

Comment: So I will just have to add a new directory in `src` named `packagename` and put the content of `src` inside `packagename`. That's it ?

Comment: If I read the documentation right, you should be able to do what you are doing, but you would then have to change your imports to `import packagename.module2a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your package with:

```
package_dir = {'': 'src'}
```

and create a `packagename` directory *in* `src`. You want to import `packagename`, not `src`. `src` is not meant to be a package itself:

```
/PackageName
    /src
        /packagename
            __init__.py
            /subpackage1
                __init__.py
                module1a.py
                module1b.py
            /subpackage2
                __init__.py
                module2a.py
                module2b.py
    /tests
    INSTALL
    LICENSE
    README
    setup.py
```

You can use relative imports between the modules anyway, but an absolute import is now

```
from package.subpackage2 import module2b
```

or you could use relative imports:

```
from ..subpackage2 import module2b
```

Sample real-life project: https://github.com/mjpieters/collective.transmogrifier

Comment: Do you mean `{'': 'src'}`?

Comment: Indeed; I copied the OP line and missed that.

Comment: Okay, that's it. A one detail, `/tests`, `INSTALL`, ..., `setup.py` must be under `/src` and not `/packagename`.

Comment: @Baptiste: ick, indeed.

Comment: I wonder if `PackageName` is still well named. Would `ProjectName` be more appropriate ?

Comment: @Baptiste: This is just the repository name, isn't it? It doesn't matter all that much which one you pick there.